# In nested directories, extract JPG from each MP4 frame, leaving JPGs in MP4's directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, ffmpeg

I have this script, which creates a directory for each file, and 
moves the file into the directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *; do
  if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
    mkdir "${file%.*}"
    mv "$file" "${file%.*}"
  fi
done
```

Now, I need to 'visit' each file (all MP4) inside its directory,
  then create a JPG from each frame with ffmpeg
  leaving JPGs inside that directory.

I create JPGs from MP4's with ..

```
ffmpeg -i FILENAME.mp4 -y -f image2 -c:v mjpeg %03d.jpg
```

I don't know how to ensure the extracted JPGs appear inside their associated MP4's directory. If I apply the ffmpeg extraction in the foregoing, JPGs will go in a higher-level directory, I think.

Comment: If you already know how to navigate the file system tree, _and_ you know how to extract frames, what part are you still missing?

Answer (score 2):

If you can't specify the output directory to `ffmpeg` itself, simply run in within the wanted directory using a subshell, e.g.

```
( cd $directory && ffmpeg ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the great suggestions.

> If you can't specify the output directory to ffmpeg itself, simply run
>   it within the wanted directory using a subshell, e.g. 
>       ( cd $directory && ffmpeg ... )

This makes sense. 
I'm not sure how $directory will be set to the correct directory in question.

I'm also not sure how I'd go back to the previous directory 
when ffmpeg is done, 
given that the tree traversal may be too complex for "cd.."

Thank you again for your kind assistance.
Eric